# Passing Variables in DBMS_SCHEDULER JOB

Tags: sql, oracle, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I have a DBMS_SCHEDULER job which executes a stored procedure, however the stored procedure needs to be passed two date values which I would like to make sysdate though when I try to do this in oracle or sqlplus the scheduled job does nothing.

```
BEGIN                      
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB ( 
   job_name        => 'JOB_QUERY',
   job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',      
   job_action      => 'BEGIN RUNREPORT(''NAME'', ''VERSION'', SYSDATE, SYSDATE); COMMIT; END;',
   start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
   repeat_interval => 'FREQ=HOURLY;BYMINUTE=10',    -- every Hour, 10 minutes in.
   end_date        => NULL, 
   enabled         => TRUE,
   comments        => 'Daily Query Update');
END;
/
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why do you need sysdate as parameter here? Can't you make sysdate as default value for that parameter in RunReport Procedure?

Comment: What do you mean, "does nothing?"  Does your job run?  Did you look at DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_JOB_ARGUMENT_VALUE  ?

Comment: Did you test this procedure alone with parameter values from your question?

Comment: Thanks @JAVA SE, setting sysdate as the default value required a bit of other changes but did end up being a good workaround. Thanks.